# UI/UX for Comparing items based on parameters side by side in an Android App

Tags: gui-design, mobile, android, experience, comparison

What is the best UX/UI for comparing three to four products based on certain set of parameters in Android app. The audience is predominantly an Android phone in portrait mode. Basically users should be able to select multiple products in a screen and then say Compare which takes them to the following UX/UI.

Currently what I am thinking is like this (scaled down to Mobile), where in the products can slide left or right and the user can see all the items compared. - But this is probably best suited for desktops and tablets, and would probably be best suited for comparison of two products.
[image]

Image courtesy: https://uxmag.com/articles/comparing-compare

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest docking the top bar (with the 3 products) and listing all the feature vertically with icons to indicate availability. I would think this approach would be the most direct and all the user would have to do is scroll down (naturally) [image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be tricky since you have to show so many informations on a very small display. Let's set on the user needs perspective, they probably are interested in comparing same informations about different products (for example comparing the "Screen size" for the 3 products. Your approach let the user see all informations of a single product, so the user should actively scroll through products, retain the informations in mind and make the comparison mentally. I prefer a "don't make me think" approach to design: showing the same information for different products all in once.

You could use select inputs to let user decide what information to show. From psychology studies we know that people usually choose items using just few informations. In the mockup I included the price as fix information (probably the main info users want to see, but I would interview them first!).
Needless to say: this works better with short texts.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f608Yv.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>